# what does _serverConnectionDiedNotification mean?

Tags: ipad, iphone-sdk-3.2

```
_serverConnectionDiedNotification. Info
 -- notification=NSConcreteNotification 0xd931a30 
{name = AVController_ServerConnectionDiedNotification; 
object = <AVController: 0xce7e340>}, 
AVController = <AVController: 0xce7e340>, currentTime = 2189.59
```

when i play a movie with movieplayercontroller,i get a black screen,and  find this notification in console of my ipad,it seems like that i lost my connection to sever.
Is it ?or you can give me some advice if you could.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a private API,it seems illegal to use it or get it.